# Set color for extra page parts visible during rubber band scroll

Tags: css, scroll, rubber-band

At least when you scroll over the edge on mac, you see the page moving down and leaving a plain color behind it. Iv'e figured out the you can change the color by setting the background color of the `body`. But is there any other approach to it? Because sometimes I need a different colors at top and bottom, etc.

Answer (score 15):

My solution has been to cheat a little bit and use a `linear-gradient()` on the `html` or `body` tag to control the segmented background colors for a given project.

Something like this should split the background in half and take care of modern browsers.

```
background: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top,
    left bottom,
    color-stop(0.5, #8BC63E),
    color-stop(0.5, #EEEEEE)
);
background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #8BC63E 50%, #EEEEEE 50%);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #8BC63E 50%, #EEEEEE 50%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #8BC63E 50%, #EEEEEE 50%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #8BC63E 50%, #EEEEEE 50%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #8BC63E 50%, #EEEEEE 50%);
```

[image: Animated GIF exhibiting scrolling beyond page bounds]

I've had mixed luck getting the same behavior on iOS, and seems to be more dependent on the specific layout.

Comment: I'm not seeing this work on body or html elements in Chrome 64.

Answer (score 7):

I need to achieve something similar.

The solution posted by @tksb doesn't work for me on Chrome (OS X), seems like Chrome uses the `background-color` to define the rubber band background, and ignores the `background-image`.

The solution I've found is to use a bit of JS

```js
// create a self calling function to encapsulate our code
(function(document, window) {
  // define some variables with initial values
  var scrollTop   = 0;
  var timeout  = null;
  
  // this function gets called when you want to
  //reset the scrollTop to 0
  function resetScrollTop() {
    scrollTop = 0;
  }

  // add an event listener to `body` on mousewheel event (scroll)
  document.body.addEventListener('mousewheel', function(evt) {
    // on each even detection, clear any previous set timer
    // to avoid double actions
    timeout && window.clearTimeout(timeout);
    
    // get the event values
    var delta = evt.wheelDelta;
    var deltaX = evt.deltaX;

    // add the amount of vertical pixels scrolled
    // to our `scrollTop` variable
    scrollTop += deltaX;
    
    console.log(scrollTop);
    
    // if user is scrolling down we remove the `scroll-up` class
    if (delta < 0 && scrollTop <= 0) {
      document.body.classList.remove('scroll-up');
    }
    // otherwise, we add it
    else if (delta > 0 && scrollTop > 0) {
      document.body.classList.add('scroll-up');
    }
    
    // if no wheel action is detected in 100ms,
    // we reset our `scrollTop` variable
    timeout = window.setTimeout(resetScrollTop, 100);
  });
})(document, window);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
body.scroll-up {
  background-color: #009688;
}
section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #fff;
}
header {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #009688;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<section id="section">
  <header>
    this demo works only on full-screen preview
  </header>
</section>
```

Here a full screen demo to test it:
http://s.codepen.io/FezVrasta/debug/XXxbMa

Comment: jQuery doesn't seem a necessity here, plain old good JS is clear enough IMHO

Comment: I find it  hard to read, a bit complicated and over engineered

Comment: I'm sorry to hear this, they are just few lines of code, maybe you could try to improve your competences with vanilla JS following some course online, @wesbos recently released a free one!

Comment: Don't be sorry, you've made a really valid point. I'll definitely touch up on my vanilla js skills

Comment: @Pipskweak I added some comments, I hope it's clear now

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate that, a lot easier to understand now!

Comment: Demo link is broken, and StackOverflow built-in demo doesn't work.